# Vector entries changing?

Tags: r

I have uploaded a SQL table to R and I am trying to replace NAs with a replacement. For some reason, the vector entries are changing from A,B,C to 1,2,3

```
unique(p$Grade)
[1] <NA> A    B    C   
Levels: A B C

qq=ifelse(is.na(p$Grade) & p$Decision_FICO>740,"A",ifelse(is.na(p$Grade) & p$Decision_FICO>680,"B","C"))

unique(qq)
[1] "B" "A" "C"

x=cbind(p$Grade,qq)

View(x)
```

When I view x, I see 2 columns, 1 named V1 and the other named qq.  I expected to see Grade and qq.

I also expected the entries in the V1 column to be A,B, or C but they are 1,2 or 3.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it turned out to be a function of level of factors (but not 100% sure).

The following worked as a solution to what I was ultimately trying to do.

```
Grade2 <- ifelse(is.na(Originations$Grade) & Originations$Decision_FICO>740,"A",ifelse(is.na(Originations$Grade) &Originations$Decision_FICO>680,"B",ifelse(is.na(Originations$Grade),"C",Originations$Grade)))

z = cbind(Originations$Grade,Grade2)

unique(z)
```

Another solution is as follows:

```
Grade1 <- Originations$Grade
Grade1[is.na(Originations$Grade)] <- "C"
Grade1[is.na(Originations$Grade) & Originations$Decision_FICO>740] <- "A"
Grade1[is.na(Originations$Grade) & Originations$Decision_FICO<=740 & Originations$Decision_FICO>680] <- "B"

unique(Grade1)

y = cbind(Originations$Grade,Grade1)

unique(y)
```